# Flutter: Use setState in a function?

Tags: flutter, dart

is there any way I can use **setState()** in a function (line 26)? I am trying to call the function **item** (which includes the **setState**) from my *main.dart* file and Flutter doesn't like that. Also, the **item** function is in a different file than the *main.dart*. Can someone please help me?

**item** function:

```
    item(itemName, color, itemVariable) {
  return Container(
    color: color ? Colors.grey[200] : Colors.white,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              "${itemVariable}x",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          itemName,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 5, 0, 10),
            child: TextField(
              onSubmitted: (value) {
                itemVariable = int.parse(value);
                print("Hodnota pro ${itemName} nastavena na: ${itemVariable}");
                setState(() {});
              },
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

*main.dart* file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intr_obleceni/items.dart';
import 'package:intr_obleceni/functions.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Main(),
        title: "Intr - seznam oblečení",
      ),
    );

class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  const Main({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainState createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Internát - seznam oblečení"),
        elevation: 2,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          category("Bundy", false),
          item("Bunda", false, Bundy.bunda),
          item("Softčílová bunda", false, Bundy.softcilovaBunda),
          category("Ostatní", true),
          item("Ručník", true, Ostatni.rucnik)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post the other dart file as well

Answer (score 2):

instead of calling the setState() function in your function, include a callback function in your params like this :

```
item(itemName, color, itemVariable {Function? callback}) {

// where you used setState(), use callback()
}
```

then in your main.dart file, where you called that item function, wrap setState in the callback function.

Comment: But I am not calling setState() in my main.dart. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Inside listview, you called item(), that is the item() function, when you set callback() function as one of your params, you can easily place setStat() inside

Comment: It says: "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void." when i put setState() in the item function.

Comment: you call item("Bunda", false, Bundy.bunda, setState) and you only need to add Function callback without ? and {}

Answer (score 0):

For those that still need an answer to this, here's what worked for me:

The safest bet is going to be to instead of using a function, to rather use a class based on the `StatefulWidget` class. My implementation went something like this:

```dart
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
    final SomeType someVariable1;
    final SomeType someVariable2;
    final SomeType someVariable3;

    const MyClass({
        required this.someVariable1,
        required this.someVariable2,
        required this.someVariable3,
        super.key,
    });

    @override
    State<MyClass> createState() => _MyClassState();

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SomeWidget(
        // you can call setState() here as needed.
        );
    }
```

This should allow you to call setState() as much as you need to within the widget that you were generating within your `item`.

The class can also then be placed into another file without causing any issues.

Hope this helps someone out somewhere.